# how to catch specific property value when i loop through objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have an array of objects with some information and one of them contains a boolean value that I want to check if it's `false` or `true` to some logic beyond the result. The problem is how I catch this value while i'm looping through objects. I made some tries but I can't solve the issue with ES6.

The objects:

```
todos:Array[4]
    0:Object
        completed:1
        id:1
        task:"go to home"
    1:Object
        completed:0
        id:2
        task:"go to work"
    2:Object
        completed:0
        id:3
        task:"study laravel"
    3:Object
        completed:0
        id:4
        task:"study Vuejs"
```

And this is my code:

```
this.todos.map((item) => {
    for (let key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key === 1) {
                console.log('done');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There are no booleans in your array of objects, please clarify your question.

Comment: `array of objects with some information and one of them contains a boolean value` . one of them =  one of objects?

Comment: what you need to achieve actually ? get completed task ? get next task after the completed task ? get all the incomplete task ? clarify your question

Comment: why the es6-promise tag spam

Comment: i want to check with completed it's value 1 i want to push it's object in array and if completed : 0 i want to push it's object in another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I'm considering the `completed` field with a value of `1` as a regular boolean `true`. You can use the same idea with an actual boolean field, when you have one in your object.

```js
let todos = [{
    completed: 1,
    id: 1,
    task: "go to home"
  },

  {
    completed: 0,
    id: 2,
    task: "go to work"
  },
  {
    completed: 0,
    id: 3,
    task: "study laravel"
  }, 
  {
    completed: 0,
    id: 4,
    task: "study Vuejs"
  }
]

todos.forEach(todo => {
  if (todo.hasOwnProperty("completed") && todo.completed === 1) {
    console.log("DONE!");
  }
})
```

Comment: In that case you can just use the `.filter()` function to generate an array of completed todos from the `todos` array directly, without having to do `.push()` explicitly - `let completedTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.hasOwnProperty("completed") && todo.completed === 1)`.